# Prevent Form from opening multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Because I'm new to C# I think this question is kind of stupid but I haven't found a solution till now that fits the problem I have.
I have two Forms. In Form1 I click a button and then a Form2 pops up where one can see a GridView. What I do is: I select rows in my first GridView (Form1) and then pass the selected rows to GridView2 in Form2. That works the first time.

```
  private void selectRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2(this);

        form2.select_rows(sender);

        if (form2.Visible)
        {
            form2.Close();
        }
        form2.Show(this);
    }
```

but now I don't know how to do this correctly. When I select more rows in my GridView1 and hit the button a second time the Form2 should stay open and the values should be just added to the existing ones in the GridView2. In my case, a new Form2 opens and the additional rows are getting put into the new Form2. I know I should check if the object is already created or move it somewhere out but how? I get Exceptions over Exceptions.

Comment: You can use Delegate and Events for awesome communication between 2 forms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{      
    public Form2 f = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        f.Show();
        f.dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow d in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            f.dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new object[] { d.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), d.Cells[1].Value.ToString() });
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "aaaa" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "bbbb" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "cccc"});
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4", "dddd"});
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

          private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();           
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Try this... Hope this help...

Comment: The third line doesn't work because my constructor in Form2 is: public Form2(Form1 frm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent(); form1 = frm1 } - so there has to be an argument in "new Form2()"

Comment: @MKX2015, Do use Form1 frm1 object for anyother purpose?

Comment: not directly frm1. I used this to make Form1 the parent form and call the second form. Is there a new constructor needed or what should be passed in new Form2()?

Comment: @MK2015, 
**public Form2 f;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            f = new Form2(this);
        }**

Comment: Ok so when I now click the button without selecting then he opens the form with the GridView. When I select something I get a  "System.ObjectDisposedException" on the form2.Show() line

Comment: Ok I have it! Need to add:  if (form2.Visible == false)
            {
                form2.Show(this);
            } to my Form1. This helps and when I leave the rows clear function out he does what I want. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the form2 outside of the method and then reference it inside your method as you already are doing, you won't want to close the form, just hide it. Maybe not even that.

You need to move the declaration into a constructor for `Form1` too

```
Form2 form2;
public Form1()
{
    form2 = new Form2(this);
}

private void selectRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(form2 == null)
        form2 = new Form2(this);

    form2.select_rows(sender);
    form2.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: Tried already. That doesn't work for me. var is undefined. "this" is not available and in my method "form2" is amigious.

Comment: Ah sorry, lazy me, 1 second

Comment: @MKX2015 - Didn't pick up on the `this`, you need to declare it in a constructor for your form

Comment: Ok I tried: public Form1(Form2 frm2)
        {
            frm2 = form2;
        } but I get a NullReference Exception. How to call that?

Comment: @MKX2015 - I'm confused where `frm2` comes from in that snippet (plus you have the declaration the wrong way round there (`form2 = frm2)`

Comment: Ok sry didn't see the update. Now he tells me that membernames musn't be identical with the enclosing type

Comment: @MKX2015 - sorry not had that before (although I've not used C# in a little bit), changing `form2` to `frm2` may fix that but you may want to give your variable a better name anyway

Comment: Doesn't fix it. The problem seems to be "public void Form1()"

Comment: @MKX2015 - sorry early morning again - remove the `void` - Basically, it needs to be a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

Comment: Nothing at all. I get a NullReference Exception even when I set it to null before.

Comment: @MKX2015 - would you mind updating your question with your updated code also? hard to see what the issue could be now

Comment: @MKX2015 - I've updated with some added error handling in the event that you do somehow make the form null, but I'm not sure how it would be null in this case

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of 3 approach.

1. Closing the first Form2 and just open a new(second) Form2 with the new value (probably the easiest way)
2. Clear the GridView on Form2 and repopulate the GridView with new values
3. Find out additional selections from Form1, only pass the addtionals to Form2, and add only the additionals to the GridView on Form2.